# Convert Expression<Func<T, object>> to Expression<Func<object>>

Tags: c#, linq, nhibernate, linq-expressions

How to convert :  `Expression<Func<T, object>>` to `Expression<Func<object>>`?

For example:

```
public class Entity
{        
    public virtual long Id { get; set; }
}
```

Origin:

```
Expression<Func<Entity, object>> origin = x => x.Id;
```

Destination:

```
Entity alias = null;
Expression<Func<object>> destination = () => alias.Id;
```

### Reason:

Actually I'm trying to create a custom cacheable ResultTransformer for Nhibernate. There is a method `public QueryOverProjectionBuilder<T> WithAlias(Expression<Func<object>> alias);` But in my classes for each particular entitites I would like to use more specific selector like `Expression<Func<T, object>>`

Comment: This question makes no sense at all, how should a method that expexts an entity be replaced by one that doesn´t? I can´t see any reason to rely on the outer scope to get rid of the methods parameter. Sounds like you´re actulally trying to solve something different. So what´s your *actual* question?

Comment: @HimBromBeere I assume he wants to "curry" the function - in this sample, by using a closure.

Answer (score 1):

You have two options:

1. Invoke the expression as Luaan suggested
2. Replace the parameters with the value you would like (a constant or a different expression)

Option 1 is as simple as `Expression.Invoke` but may not be compatible with libraries such as LINQ. Option 2 is best done using an expression visitor:

```
    private class ExchangeParametersVisitor : ExpressionVisitor
    {
        public ParameterExpression Parameter { get; set; }
        public Expression Value { get; set; }

        protected override Expression VisitParameter(ParameterExpression node)
        {
            if (node == Parameter)
            {
                return Value;
            }
            return node;
        }
    }
```

What you need to do is apply the visitor to the body of your lambda expression and use it to create a new lambda expression that contains all parameters as before except the one you replaced.

Comment: A nice example of replacing the parameters :) Though I have to note that you need to make sure `Value` has no side-effects - otherwise replacing the parameter expression will cause trouble. Using a variable would be better, but I'm afraid that the same systems that reject `Invoke` will also not support variables :)

Comment: @Luaan Yes. Since variables are afaik not supported by the C#-compiler for a use in expressions, I think it is even more unlikely for an expression parser to accept variables than invokes of an expression.

Comment: The C# compiler doesn't support block-like expressions at all, sadly, which includes variables. And most people don't think of languages like F# when designing their libraries. To be fair, it's not always easy to translate things like this - but e.g. EF does support `let`, which can be used in a similar way. E.g. `Expression<Func<string, int>> inner = x => (from a in x let b = a - '0' select b).Sum();`, which translates to two "nested" `Select`s.

Answer (score 1):

That's what `Expression.Invoke` is for.

Create a new lambda expression, and use `Expression.Invoke` on the original expression to compose the two expressions.

Sample:

```
Expression<Func<string, int>> inner = x => int.Parse(x);
var outer = Expression.Lambda<Func<int>>
              (Expression.Invoke(inner, Expression.Constant("123")));

outer.Compile()().Dump(); // 123
```

Sadly, some expression parsers don't handle `Invoke` correctly - they assume it to be an invocation of a method, and reject it. In that case, you need to *inline* the expression. That means visiting the whole inner expression and replacing the `ParameterExpression`s with variables in the better case, or if parser doesn't support that either, inlining the argument in all the places.